# How do I communicate between an ASP.NET wep app and a Windows service?

Tags: asp.net, windows-services

On the same server I have a Windows service and an ASP.NET web app. What is the best way to communicate between them? I need to pass small amounts of data both ways.

I also need to pass the user windows identity making the request of the web app (the web app uses windows identity authentication) to the service. Both programs are ours so it's ok to pass the user as a string (as opposed to a WindowsIdentity object).

There can be multiple simultaneous requests.

Is named pipes the best bet? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I used MSMQ to arrange this kind of communication. Surely it's not the only option.